# Including a .SWF file in a C# Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, flash

I'm currently working on a project where i need to include a application page for users. I need the users to access few .SWF flash games through this page. I created a folder named applications in the Application and imported the .SWF files into that. After that I tried directly linking them using a hyperlink on my page, but they don't seem to open :/
am i missing something? or is there something else i need to do before that?

Would really appreciate it if you can help

Thank you

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: Its just that i don't know why it won;t work, there's no code involved, all i have done now is linking a .SWF file to a HYPERLINK. The linked SWF File is in one of my folders on the application.

e.g: Linking an Image to a page? I've done pretty much that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can just hyperlink to your .swf file. According to [this](http://animation.about.com/od/flashanimationtutorials/qt/embedswfwebpage.htm) site, and your using Dreamweaver or FrontPage, you can just insert it from the Insert menu (or something of the kind). If you aren't using either of those two, you can edit you .swf file in Flash and choose "Export as HTML" from the file menu (or where ever it is) and then just copy the source code of the resulting file to your webpage.

Comment: I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 environment

Comment: @Suits999, does it matter what environment your using?

Comment: its directed at the question above as he was referring to Dreamweaver or Front page

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should be able to open .swf files directly in your browser, although embedding the swf into your html is often a good idea, you don't have to. 
If the url in your address bar shows an adress ending with '.swf' you can test if a swf has loaded by right clicking in your browser window, if you see the flash context menu (zoom in, zoom out, etc) Your swf has loaded.

If your swf has loaded, but nothing else happens, there can be many other reasons for this.

Where did you get the swf game files? If you copied them from another site it's very likely that the swf is supposed to load other files (game assets (images), settings (xml) etc) before the game can be played.

Sometimes the execution of (actionscript) code in a swf is triggered by script in the html page it is embedded in.

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do....

Comment: They are very small flash games from sites such as "miniclip", which just run on the flash player when executed normally. so i highly doubt there are any other xml or image files that are associated with it :/ I'm guessing it's some other reason? could it be because I'm linking them to Aspx pages?

Comment: The fact that you create your links in asp.net shouldn't make a difference, Do you get the url of the swf in the address bar after clicking your link?

Comment: yes they do work locally, and yes the link does show up when u open the hyperlink in a new window but there's nothing there, just a white page? :/

Comment: Does the white page contain a swf or not?, what does your NET panel in firebug say? Is the swf file acually loaded?

Comment: If a swf loads something (assets or xml) from another domain, that will work if you run the file locally, but not if you run the swf in a different domain than where the assets are. This you can also detect with firebug. You can see what requests are being made and what the response is.